# Auth with Laravel Sanctum and JWT Token

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-sanctum

this is my controller

```
 public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

this is my auth.php

```
  'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

and this is my logout form in blade.php file

```
    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post"> @method('POST') @csrf <button>logout</button> </form>
```

i wrote my logout request on api.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

});
```

my other method (login , register and show userpage) works but only logout doesn't work.
my logout page redirect to api/login url and it says GET method not allowed here. Only POST method.

this is my full controller code
https://github.com/sksmsWKd/MetaComposerProto/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

Comment: In `routes/api.php`, wrap all routes with the prefix `api`. Change the route name to `api.logout`

Comment: @sta should i do like this? Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->prefix('api')->name('register'); Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->prefix('api')->name('login'); Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->prefix('api')->group(function () { Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->prefix('api')->name('api.logout'); Route::post('user', function (Request $request) { dd($request); })->name('user'); });

Comment: if your route located in `routes/api.php` then `api` prefix is already there

Comment: @sta thanks.  Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->prefix('api')->name('api.logout')   this naming is right??

Comment: Change this and try `{{ route('auth.logout') }}`

Comment: @sta sorry it doesn't work. it still shows get method cannot use error